# Windows Universal Menu Bar color

Tags: statusbar, win-universal-app, menubar

I have looked on Windows Universal Apps documentation, but havent found. How to change the Menu Bar color on Universal Apps?

Example: the dark blue MenuBar on Windows 10 Mail App

Answer (score 1):

Change the background color of title bar when the app launched.

code:

```
void InitializeTitleBar()
{
    var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    // Title bar colors. Alpha must be 255.
    titleBar.BackgroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 22, G = 100, B = 167 };
    titleBar.ForegroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 255, G = 255, B = 255 };
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 22, G = 100, B = 167 };

    titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = new Color() { A = 255, R = 255, G = 255, B = 255 };
}
```

[image]